# map hilight jquery does not work correctly with Bootstrap 4 - image hover not being highlighted

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, maphilight

When I add the (jquery.maphilight.js) map highlight and also add the plugin bootstrap 4, it does not work and no longer shows the 'highlighted' area on mouseover, the bootstrap seems to disable the maphilight.

Map-highlight without the bootstrap works correctly

Can anyone please help?? Thanks in advance!
The sample html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css" title="style">


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.map').maphilight({
        fillColor: '008800'
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <img src="../_scrum/images/big_pic.jpg" width="671" height="514" border="0" usemap="#bigpic" alt="" class="map">
  <map id="bigpic" name="bigpic">

<area shape="rect" coords="3,116,28,334" href="#inspection" alt="inspection" title="Part of the Scrum Pillars - to Inspect system demos" class="group">
    <area shape="rect" coords="20,219,175,272" href="#sprintbacklog" alt="sprintbacklog" title="These are items to be worked on by the scrum team during a sprint" class="group" >
    <area shape="rect" coords="19,276,176,325" href="#goal" alt="goal" title="Sprint Goal is the objective the scrum team will focus on during the execution of the sprint" class="group" >
    <area shape="rect" coords="181,157,267,238" href="#po" alt="Product Owner" title="One member of the development team, to prioritise backlog items and is the owner for the product backlog" class="group" >
</map>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because you are including 2 versions of jQuery. The highlight plugin is attached to the first and gets wiped out by the second when it creates a whole new jQuery object. Don't add the second version

Comment: @charlietfl thank you! Obviously I have a lot to learn on my jQuery journey … but thanks for your prompt response !